# How does Ubuntu keep persistent access permissions for mount points of automatically per-user mounted devices?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, automounting

I am trying to figure out how to manage `ext4` formatted external hard drives and I have stumbled upon a behaviour that I do not understand.

I noticed that if I change access permissions (or ownership) of mount points of automatically per-user mounted devices under `/media`, the change is persistent, even though the mount point disappears after unmounting the device.  To help me understand the implications of this, could someone explain to me how it works?

Here is an example of this behaviour with an `ext4` formatted USB flash stick:

```
§ ls -l /media/alexey/
total 4
drwx------ 3 alexey alexey 4096 déc.  23 21:25 Corsair
§ chmod g+rwx /media/alexey/Corsair/
§ ls -l /media/alexey/
total 4
drwxrwx--- 3 alexey alexey 4096 déc.  23 21:25 Corsair
§ umount /media/alexey/Corsair 
§ ls -l /media/alexey/
total 0
§ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc
Mounted /dev/sdc at /media/alexey/Corsair.
§ ls -l /media/alexey/
total 4
drwxrwx--- 3 alexey alexey 4096 déc.  23 21:25 Corsair
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must separate between a directory and a (directory used as a) mountpoint.  When you mount a file-system *"on-top of"* a directory, that directory (and all files and directory under it) becomes obscured - covered if you like - by the file-system you mounted "over" it.  The changes you made, was done to the filesystem *on your USB-pen*, and thus remain between mounts - not on the (transient) directory used as just a mount-point for it (which is created anew - with default permission - each time it's needed).  In essence, the top/root (**/**) of the filesystem on you USB-pen, *"becomes"* the mount-point!

---

On your USB-pen, there is a separate filesystem with it's own root (**/**).

When you plug-in your USB-pen, a directory called **Corsair** is created - with some default permission and ownership under **/media/alexey**.

Then the root-filesystem on the USB-pen is mounted *"on-top of"* the **/media/alexey/Corsair**-directory - obscuring it.  From now on when you do something (like changing permission or ownership) to the **Corsair** directory, you're *actually* changing things to the root-directory on your *USB-pen*.

When you unmount the USB-pen, the **Corsair** directory is deleted.  But the filesystem on the USB-pen - with any changes you made to it, including to the root of it - remains.

When you plug-in the USB-pen again, a new **Corsair** directory is created with default permission - and *no* memory from what was done last time.  However when the USB-pen's filesystem and *it's* root is mounted on top of the directory, the changes you made will still be there - because the changes was done *on your USB-pen*, not the transient directory.

Comment: Thanks, it feels like i could have figured that out if i wasn't tired...